# python opencv with docker: Matplotlib.show Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend

Tags: python, docker, opencv, matplotlib, xorg

I need to run opencv + python in docker.

This code should show a **GUI** popup with an image:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.imshow(img_rgb)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**It works fine on a ubuntu desktop** but the problem is with docker. I got this error:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, 
which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()
```

Following some post, if I add this

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

I got another similar error:

```
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which 
requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 
'headless' is currently running
```

#### attempts

- I installed tinker
- I launched the container with .Xauthority  && /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
- I tried almost all the answers of

  - ["UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure." when plotting figure with pyplot on Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656777/userwarning-matplotlib-is-currently-using-agg-which-is-a-non-gui-backend-so)
  - [How can I use matplotlib.pyplot in a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018102/how-can-i-use-matplotlib-pyplot-in-a-docker-container)
  - [Tails - Package 'python3-tk' has no installation candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553144/tails-package-python3-tk-has-no-installation-candidate)
- Almost every answer is for os with desktop, not for docker

#### workaround

I know that runs GUI applications is not the goal of docker, but I want to use docker to have my operative system clean while I developing on python.

If I change the **show()** by **plt.savefig("mygraph.png")** , the image is created instead the gui popup.

#### steps to replicate the issue with ubuntu

- docker run

```
docker run -it  \
--workdir=/app \
-v /your/workspace:/app \
-v /tmp/.X11-unix/X0:$XSOCK -e DISPLAY=0  \
jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv  bash
```

- install matplotlib

```
pip install matplotlib
```

- add the [python code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-an-object-with-opencv-python/) and run it with: python main.py